# Missed Apple Keyboard Recall Window: What are my Options?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, repair, warranty

Not sure whether to ask this in the apple or law SE but it's very apple specific, so I'll ask here. I own a 2016 MacBook pro that I bought second-hand. Some of the keys get stuck, which was the reason Apple offers a complimentary repair service for affected models. I've known this for a while but I only now got around to taking my MB to a repair store. They informed me that the "quality program" as they call it is only valid for up to 4 years after purchase. Replacing the keyboard now would cost over $600. Are there any options to get apple to pay for the repair once the repair window has closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Once the 4 year extended warranty program elapses the computer is no longer covered. This, of course, is problematic given that the issue recurs regardless of the age of the computer or previous repairs.

Since current models do not suffer this issue, the only real solution is to get a new computer - or pay the repair price.

Comment: I was afraid you might say that. I'll wait some more to see whether there are any differing opinions before accepting your answer.